# cascading style sheet doesn't work with angular Js

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with angularJs with angular-ui bootstrap framework, my problem I don't able to apply css rules to my web page.

My index.html routes

```
.state("home",{
        url:"Home",
        views:{
            'main':{templateUrl:"home.html"}
        }
    })

     .state("forum",{
        url:"forum",
        views:{
            'main3':{templateUrl:"forum.html"}
        }
    })
```

Forum.html ** bg color is not blue !**

```
<html>
<body style='background-color:blue'>
<h1>Forum</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you check for any possible errors in your console?

Comment: Open devtools and check where this background redefined

Comment: No errors with console

Comment: You most likely don't want to have the html and body tags in each templateUrl.

Comment: why does your template has a `html` tag ? it should appear only once

Comment: @svarog thank you I get rid off html and body tags and it works .

Comment: @svarog  please write your suggestion as an answer in order to accept it

Answer (score 0):

As svarog suggested the problem was from  tag,I delete both Html and body tag and my page works fine.

```
<div  style="background-color:blue">
<div class="tab-content">
<div ui-view="main3">
</div>
<h1>Forum</h1> 
</div>
</div>
```